# Button required to start/stop javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm not great with javascript. I can look something up on the web and just about get it into a document, but I'm pretty much a 'noob', so please be patient.

I have the following;

```
<iframe src="" name="frame" id="frame" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var frames = Array('http://www.google.com/', 3,
'http://www.yahoo.com/', 3,
'http://www.ask.com/', 3,
'http://www.dogpile.com/', 3);
var i = 0, len = frames.length;
function ChangeSrc()
{
if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;
</script>
```

Which pretty much does what I want, which is reloading the contents of an iframe on a loop. Now, how would I go about implementing a Start button, and a stop button. I understand my code will start its reloading loop on page load...so what I'd like to do is open the page with the iframe on, and the script doesn't start until the 'START' button is clicked, and then stops when the 'STOP' button is pressed.

Like I said, I'm not great with javascript, I'm learning as I go, so if someone could take my code, insert the buttons code and repost then I'll be forever grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `setTimeout` use `x=setInterval(...)` which has it's own iterations so you don't need a recursive function. This also returns a handle `x`, which can be used to stop the loop with `clearInterval(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that will store whether you are restarting:

```
var loop = false;
```

Now, insert a button:

```
<input type="button" name="loop" id="loop" value="START LOOP" onclick="startStop();" />
```

Also, we need to create a function called startStop();

```
function startStop(){
    // Below is shorthand to invert the value of the loop variable from true to false.
    loop = !loop;
    // I guess we're also like to change the text on the loop button to say start or stop
    // below we are using shorthand for if(loop === true) print "STOP" else print "START"
    document.getElementById("loop").value = loop ? "STOP LOOP" : "START LOOP";
    // then we need to call your function, because we want to restart the loop or stop it after clicking
    ChangeSrc();
}
```

Then we need to add a checker in your recursive function that cancels the loop if loop is not set.

```
function ChangeSrc(){
    // if loop is NOT true (aka false), return and don't continue the function
    if(!loop) return;
    if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
    document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
    setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
```

In case of your timeout: you can actually call your function by just passing ChangeSrc without the string and without the brackets, this passes the name of the function that will be called in the timeout: `setTimeout(ChangeSrc, (frames[i++] * 1000));`. It just looks a bit cleaner.

#### Update

So the total code would look like this:

```
<iframe src="" name="frame" id="frame" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
<input type="button" name="loop" id="loop" value="START LOOP" onclick="startStop();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// I added the new keyword here, it works without but its better with! You could also just wrap it in []
var frames = new Array(
    'http://www.google.com/', 3,
    'http://www.yahoo.com/', 3,
    'http://www.ask.com/', 3,
    'http://www.dogpile.com/', 3
);
var i = 0, 
    len = frames.length, 
    loop = false;
function ChangeSrc(){
    if(!loop) return;
    if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
    document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
    setTimeout(ChangeSrc, (frames[i++]*1000));
}
function startStop(){
    loop = !loop;
    document.getElementById("loop").value = loop ? "STOP LOOP" : "START LOOP";
    ChangeSrc();
}
// I've removed your window.onload because the button will allow you to start the loop
</script>
```

Comment: `loop = loop ? false : true` What's wrong with `loop = !loop`?

Comment: I actually honestly never really thought about it :) Just got used to this. Will actually amend it.

Comment: @somethinghere - thanks for taking the time to reply, however, I have no idea where to put your code. I'm a novice, apologies if I gave the impression I may be able to implement this without you providing the whole, complete code.

Comment: @AdamH I updated your code with my changes and cleaned your code up a bit (nicer spacing, easier to read). I tested it and it works.

Comment: You absolute legend. It works, thanks so much. Marking your answer as correct right away! :)

Comment: No problem. Does it make sense though? Since its better to understand than to copy :)

Comment: In all honesty, not right at this second. But I'm staring at the code right now, trying to pick it apart and understand each bit. As I mentioned, it's a little alien to me right now but I'm studying basic javascript, so I'm sure as I progress, it will start making more sense. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick workaround for that:

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="" name="frame" id="frame" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var needToRun = false
    var frames = Array('http://www.google.com/', 3,
            'http://www.yahoo.com/', 3,
            'http://www.ask.com/', 3,
            'http://www.dogpile.com/', 3);
    var i = 0, len = frames.length;
    function ChangeSrc() {
        if (needToRun) {
            if (i >= len) {
                i = 0;
            } // start over
            document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
            setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++] * 1000));
        }
    }

    $('#start').click(function() {
        needToRun = true;
        ChangeSrc();
    });

    $('#stop').click(function() {
        needToRun = false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Who mentioned they were using JQuery?

Comment: @lolka_bolka - thanks for your reply. I have no strong feeling whether the code should be jquery or javascript :) However, I still can't get this to work :(

Comment: anyway, what is thos 3 after each url in your array?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that link out. Any extra knowledge at this point is more than welcome :) and the 3...that specifies the amount of time before reloading the next source, so that would be 3 seconds :)